# Select printer in Java to print JasperReport

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

Im trying to print JasperReport to specific printer in Java. I found this code but it doesnt work.

```
public void print(JasperPrint jp, String impresora) {

    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        // printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); //setting page size
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        PrinterName printerName = new PrinterName(impresora, null); //gets printer

        PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
        printServiceAttributeSet.add(printerName);

        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelo Impresion");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to send the report to specific printer?

Note: I know the name of the printer so i dont need to navigate arround system printers to find the target printer.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work" please.

Comment: Yes, sorry. 

The code doesnt do anything. No error or excetion, simply it doesnt work. The guy who posted that code says it works for him